# Hibernate custom UserType owner is null in nullSafeGet method

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to create a custom type for a `jsonb` column in my PostgreSQL server. The Java type is polymorphic. My goal is to use another column in the entity to determine what class to deserialize too, rather than relying upon extra properties generated by Jackson's `@JsonTypeInfo`, such as `@class`.

I'll simplify the code for brevity sake.

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_activity', schema = "user_")
@TypeDef(name = "UserActivityDetailsType", typeClass = UserActivityDetailsType.class)
public final class UserActivity implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "bigserial")
  private Long id;

  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  private User user;

  @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "user_activity_type_t")
  @Convert(converter = UserActivityType.UserActivityTypeConverter.class)
  private UserActivityType type; // An enum.

  @Column(name = "details", nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  @Type(type = "UserActivityDetailsType")
  private UserActivityDetails details;

  ...

}
```

Here is `UserActivityDetails`:

```
public abstract class UserActivityDetails implements Serializable {

  ...

}
```

And `UserActivityDetailsType`:

```
public final class UserActivityDetailsType implements UserType {

  ...

  @Override
  public final Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet rs, final String[] names, final SharedSessionContractImplementor session, final Object owner)
      throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    // "owner" is of the type "UserActivity", but all fields are null except "id".

    ...
  }

  ...

}
```

Why is `owner` not completely initialized? Is this intended functionality? Again, my goal is to deserialize based on another column, specifically the value of the field `UserActivity#type`.

I hope a minimal reproducible example is not necessary here, and would just add unnecessary noise to my post. Please let me know if I should share more code.

Comment: that is actually interesting why owner in you case is not null, because HBN typically loads data in the following way: resultset -> Object[] -> entity, i.e. in transforms resultset row in array and after that constructs entity

Comment: If that's true, why would the `owner` argument exist?

Comment: to support loading of lazy fields, collections, etc

Comment: I guess my goal then is to set the `details` field only after the `type` field is set. I could map the column to a string, add a `UserActivityDetails` fields marked with `@Transient`, and use a `@PostLoad` method to deserialize then. This isn't ideal.

Comment: another option is to use `type` as discriminator column and define different entity classes for different `type`'s, not sure this is better though.

Comment: Ha, I was just going to this page to comment the same idea.

Comment: and another idea is to implement `CompositeUserType`: if target JSON representation depends on another field, that means we must always query those fields together (think about query `select id, details from UserActivity` - it has no chance to return correct result)